# DataGridView Validating combobox selection

Tags: vb.net, winforms

My datagridview has a combobox column, the combobox has 2 values. Let's just say "A" and "B" are the values.

When data is loaded to the datagridview the columns values are empty, number of rows doesn't matter but only 1 row can have the value "A" and only 1 row can have the value "B".

I tried this in the `CellValidating` event

```
If e.ColumnIndex = 5 Then
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dg.Rows
        If row.Cells(5).Value = e.FormattedValue Then
            e.Cancel = True
            dg.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = "Invalid Value"
        Else
            dg.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = ""
        End If
    Next
End If
```

I can see how this doesn't work, my problem is i'm validating each row including the one i'm currently editing. So how do I properly validate this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at a workstation to test this out.  I'm thinking you should use Value instead of FormattedValue.  You could also try to do this in the CellValueChanged event.
MSDN states: The Value property is the actual data object contained by the cell, whereas the FormattedValue is the formatted representation of this object.

```
If e.ColumnIndex = 5 Then
    Dim CurrValue as string = dg.rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).value.ToString
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dg.Rows
        If row.Cells(5).Value.ToString = CurrValue Then
            e.Cancel = True
            dg.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = "Invalid Value"
        Else
            dg.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = ""
        End If
    Next
End If    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that confirms there isn't a duplicated value for a specific column and call it from the the CellValidating Event Handler.  In this case you'll call it twice (once for A and once for B).

```
Private Function DoesCellContainDuplicatedValue(ByVal intColumnToCheck As Integer, _
                                                ByVal intCurrentRow As Integer, _
                                                ByVal strValue As String) As Boolean

    Dim bolCellContainsDuplicateValue As Boolean = False

    Dim intCursor As Integer = 0

    Do Until intCursor = DataGridView1.Rows.Count OrElse bolCellContainsDuplicateValue = True

        'Don't check the old value for the cell we're checking.     
        If intCursor <> intCurrentRow AndAlso DataGridView1.Rows(intCursor).Cells(0).Value = strValue Then

            bolCellContainsDuplicateValue = True

        End If

        intCursor += 1

    Loop

    Return bolCellContainsDuplicateValue

End Function
```

Then in your Event Handler:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValidating(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValidating

    If e.ColumnIndex = 5 AndAlso e.FormattedValue = "A" AndAlso DoesCellContainDuplicatedValue(5, e.RowIndex, "A") Then

        e.Cancel = True

        MsgBox("You cannot have more than one A value.")

    End If

    If e.ColumnIndex = 5 AndAlso e.FormattedValue = "B" AndAlso DoesCellContainDuplicatedValue(5, e.RowIndex, "B") Then

        e.Cancel = True

        MsgBox("You cannot have more than one B value.")

    End If

End Sub
```